# MapView slow to load on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-mapview

I programmatically created mapview in an android fragment: [Programmatically Creating MapView and Adding a Marker Results in a null pointer exception in the fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772621/programmatically-creating-mapview-and-adding-a-marker-results-in-a-null-pointer)

However, I am getting the following error while trying to load:

```
01-20 15:50:02.337 3542-3692/? E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mypackage-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mypackage-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.example.mypackage-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Here is the mapView:

[image]

**Note:** It's stuck forever like that. Not sure what's the problem. Also, I am using Eclipse for building my project (It's not updated to use Android Studio).

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It started working after following this:

[Android Map loading very slow/not loading at all in started activity until clicking on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908988/android-map-loading-very-slow-not-loading-at-all-in-started-activity-until-click)

```
   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the below 3 lines to MapView tag in xml

```
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"
```

Comment: Tried the above solution, it loads the googleMaps fast, but it fixed the google map in one place & i want moveable GoogleMaps